# Web deployment error - Logfile provider may not support this deployment

Tags: c#, .net, iis

Im having some issues regarding Web deploy 2.0 both for Azure websites and for my own server. The setup builds perfectly but i get this error message:

Error   31  Web deployment task failed. ((08-08-2014 14:02:00) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Child object 'customFields' cannot be added to object 'logFile'. The 'logFile' provider may not support this deployment.        0   0   NopCommerceStore

---

And a logdump from my own server:

Content-Type: application/msdeploy
Version: 9.0.0.0
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.1762.0
MSDeploy.Method: Sync
MSDeploy.RequestId: e01ecae3-b97b-43c6-9bfb-4a6f69a9e170
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: da-DK
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: da-DK
ServerVersion: 9.0.1762.0
Skip: objectName="^configProtectedData$"
Provider: auto, Path: 
A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID 'e01ecae3-b97b-43c6-9bfb-4a6f69a9e170'. Request Timestamp: '08-08-2014 14:02:04'. Error Details:
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: Child object 'customFields' cannot be added to object 'logFile'. The 'logFile' provider may not support this deployment.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.AddChild(DeploymentObject source, Int32 position, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAddChild(DeploymentObject destParent, DeploymentObject sourceObject, Int32 position)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)

 
 
  AspNetModuleDiagErrorEvent
  
   Module
  
 
 
  {06A01367-79D3-4594-8EB3-C721603C4679}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the error. A reference to a WPF binary was causing the trouble. I Just removed all unnecessary references and the problem disappeared :)